# PHP object properties

Tags: php, properties

I'm new to OOP in PHP and I find the difference between the following two expressions difficult to understand.

```
    $object->$foo;
    $object->foo;
```

Maybe it's my fault, but I could not find the relevant part in the manual.

Comment: It's `ClassName::$foo` for accessing static properties and `$object->foo` for accessing object members

Comment: @RoyalBg, Correct. But OP was confused with where to put the `$` symbol.

Comment: @RoyalBg Thanks for the extra info about static properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call `$obj->$foo` is using a so called variable variable. Check this:

```
class A { 
    public $foo = 1;
}

$a = new A();
$foo = 'foo';

// now you can use both
echo $a->$foo;
echo $a->foo;
```

Follow the manual about [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Nice one hek, Perfect. **+1**

Comment: Thanks :) I must admit that my first, sunday morning, look also told me that the first line is wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, in order to fully understand the somewhat odd-looking `$object->$foo`, you should understand two things about PHP:

### Variable names

Most of the time variables in PHP are quite straight-forward. They begin with a `$` sign, have one `[a-zA-Z_]` character, and then any amount of `[a-z-A-Z0-9_]` characters. Examples include:

```
$var  = 'Abcdef';
$_GET = [];
$a1   = 123;
// And so on...
```

Now, PHP variables can actually be named pretty much *anything*, as long as the name is, or can be cast to, a [scalar type](http://php.net/is_scalar). The way you name a variable with anything is to use curly braces (`{}`), like this:

```
${null}  = 'It works'; echo ${null};
${false} = 'It works'; echo ${false};
${'!'}   = 'It works'; echo ${'!'};

// Slightly weirder...
${(int)trim(' 5 ')}       = 'It works'; echo ${5};
${implode(['a','b','c'])} = 'It works'; echo $abc;
```

**Important:** Just because you *can* do this does not mean you should, however. It is mostly just an oddity of PHP that you can do this.

### Variable variables

A somewhat convoluted explanation: *A variable variable is a variable that is accessed using a variable name*.

A much easier way to understand variable variables is to use what we just learning about variable names in PHP. Take this example:

```
${"abc"} = 'Abc...';
echo $abc;
```

We create a variable using the string, `"abc"`, which can also be accessed using `$abc`.

Now, there is no reason (or rule) that says it has to be a string.... it can also be *a variable*:

```
$abc = 'Abc...';
$varName = 'abc';
echo ${$varName}; // echo $abc
```

That is basically a variable variable. "Real" variable variables just do not use the curly braces:

```
$abc = 'Abc...';
$varName = 'abc';
echo $$varName; // echo $abc
```

### As for the question

In the question the `$object->$foo` thing is basically just an "object variable variable", if you like

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object->abc = 'The alphabet!';

$foo = 'abc';
echo $object->$foo;
echo $object->{$foo};  // The same
echo $object->{'abc'}; // The same
```

Object variable variables can be somewhat useful, but they are rarely necessary. Using an associative array is usually a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for extending the view. Very useful.